# interactive mode vs animation - python

Tags: python

Is it better matplotlib interactive mode or matplotlib animation in terms of performance?

I have a continous flow of data coming from the serial port. I get 2 measures let's say var1 and var2. I need to plot them in a 3d plot adding the 3th dimension, the time. I've tried different approches based on ion, but i couldn't get what i want. I've seen many examples of animation, but no one is suitable for my purpose. I was arguing which one ion or animate is quicker, since the flow of data has a high frequency update. So i need to update data var1 as x and var2 as y and have a sliding z axis, the time is flowing.

Also, is there a something similar to "set_xdata" in a 3d plot?

Comment: `matplotlib interactive mode or matplotlib animation` Do you mean interactive vs. script, the different backend, or creating animations directly in or without matplotlib? What do you want to achieve in both cases?

Comment: i mean [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) for interactive, usualy followed by matplotlib.pyplot.draw(). 

i mean [this](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/animate_decay.html) for animate

Comment: i need to know which one is better in performance, since i need to plot a flow of continous data from the serial (or socket).

Comment: I don't get it. Please **describe** your situation, problems, experience and desired output **in detail**.

Comment: I have a continous flow of data coming from the serial port. I get 2 measures let's say var1 and var2. I need to plot them in a 3d plot adding the 3th dimension, the time. I've tried different approches based on ion, but i couldn't get what i want. I've seen many examples of animation, but no one is suitable for my purpose. I was arguing which one ion or animate is quicker, since the flow of data has a high frequency update. So i need to update data var1 as x and var2 as y and have a sliding z axis, the time is flowing.

Comment: almost same question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863630/3dplot-continous-data

Comment: Please edit your question to include these (and more) details. Also, how exactly is this question different? [Cross-posting](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/156) is discouraged on the StackExchange network, so people don't waste their time with an answer you already received on the other site.

Comment: here i asked the performance, there i asked the code. sebix asked for more info, maybe i'm not able to make my question clear.

Comment: Here you're also asking about the `set_xdata`. Have you tried just trying both and comparing the results?

Comment: yes, i apologize for set_xdata part of the question. No i didn't try, because using animation seems not easy as ion. And this is why i asked this question, i would like to avoid spending a lot of time on animation way if it's not quick enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.animation` is a nice approach because you can specify the frame or update rate. Here you have an example of a 3d animation, including a comment about `set_data` for 3D plots:

http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html

Here you have another example plotting data coming from an Arduino board:

https://gist.github.com/electronut/d5e5f68c610821e311b0

In general, using your own logic mixing `plt.ion`, `plt.draw` and such is more complicated than using `matplotlib.animation`, so I recommend you to use the latter because it is specifically meant for this kind of task and *I guess* the performance would be better.